# Saving file path in a variable using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, filepath

I'm using tkinter to create a GUI for an old script I have, but I'm stuck right now.
I want to click a button to open the "Search File" window, choose a specific file and save its path in a variable.
The code I have is able to open the window, then I can select the file and display it's path, but I couldn't find a way to save this path in a variable.
This is what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def get_file_path():
    # Open and return file path
    file_path= filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
    l1 = Label(window, text = "File path: " + file_path).pack()

window = Tk()
# Creating a button to search the file
b1 = Button(window, text = "Open File", command = get_file_path).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Using a global is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global variable:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def get_file_path():
    global file_path
    # Open and return file path
    file_path= filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
    l1 = Label(window, text = "File path: " + file_path).pack()

window = Tk()
# Creating a button to search the file
b1 = Button(window, text = "Open File", command = get_file_path).pack()
window.mainloop()
print(file_path)
```

Once your windows closed, you'll get your file_path.

Comment: This does work. However, if I want to use "file_path" as the parameter for other function, it's returned that it is still not defined. I have this issue if I use
`l4 = Label(window, text = "This video has " + str(count_frames(file_path)) + " frames.")` under 
`b1 = Button(window, text = "Open File", command = get_file_path).pack()` (count_frames returns the number of frames of a video in a given file path). How can the code be improved to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You could declare `file_path` as global variable in `get_file_path`

```
def get_file_path():
    global file_path
    # Open and return file path
    file_path= filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
    l1 = Label(window, text = "File path: " + file_path).pack()
```

Then you can access that variable from anywhere in the script

------Edit------
According to what you said in your comment, i say you could use `tkinter.StringVar` to save the file path, and then to access it later when calling `count_frames` as an argument.

It could be implemented as the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

file_path_var = StringVar()

def get_file_path():
    # Open and return file path
    file_path= filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
    file_path_var.set(file_path) #setting the variable to the value from file path
    #Now the file_path can be acessed from inside the function and outside
    file_path_var.get() # will return the value stored in file_path_var
    l1 = Label(window, text = "File path: " + file_path).pack()

window = Tk()
# Creating a button to search the file
b1 = Button(window, text = "Open File", command = get_file_path).pack()
# will also return the value saved in file_path_var
file_path_var.get()
window.mainloop()
print(file_path)
```

So now where ever your `count_frames` function is, as long as you have selcted a file first you should be able to just do

```
count_frames(file_path_var.get())
```

Comment: Hey Jojo
As I said to Panda50, this does work. However, if I try to use this global variable in as a parameter of another function, I still get the same problem. If I use l4 = Label(window, text = "This video has " + str(count_frames(file_path)) + " frames.") , it still doesnt work (count_frames returns the number of frames of a video in a given file path).